# Meteor data subscription lifecycle

Tags: meteor

I'd like to better understand how the subscription model works - let's say I have some global subscriptions ie. they are loaded when the client starts, assuming it's the client's first connection to the Meteor server then all required data will be populated in minimongo and kept in sync with the server for the duration of the session.

But what happens when the client closes the app and reconnects at later stage:

1. Is the local store kept indefinitely on the client?
2. If above is true, then when the user re-connects would the data be synced to handle any differences between the local and server dbs?

Answer (score 0):

Minimongo is an in-memory javascript datastore. Because it is not persisted to disk, none of the data will be available after the client browser/tab is closed. When a client reconnects, minimongo will be empty and all active subscription data will be synced as if for the first time.